# Sorting varchar column by number, character

Tags: sql, postgresql, natural-sort

I have a `varchar column [flat_number]` which has some values as

```
A1A1A
A1A2A
A1A101A
A3A5A
12
A2
A3
```

I wish to get the results sorted by number and then by characters first

like

```
12
A2
A3
A1A1A
A1A2A
A1A101A
A3A5A
```

I have managed to sort it by number (if the column only contains digits 0-9 using regex, I treat it as a number), then I sort it by character, but it dosent seem to work for column values as A1A101A (having multiple combinations of number and character)

```
CASE
  WHEN length(flat_number) < 10 AND flat_number SIMILAR TO '[0-9]+'
THEN
  flat_number::int
END
ELSE
  NULL
END,
( SELECT COALESCE( match[1], NULL ) FROM regexp_matches( flat_number, '[^0-9]+' ) AS match ),
( SELECT COALESCE( left( match[1], 9), NULL ) FROM regexp_matches( flat_number, '([0-9]+$)' ) AS match )::int
```

The current query works as

If the column contains only numbers [0-9] I convert it to int and sort it
ElSE, I split the column into 2 parts and try to extract the column character at the start and the number at the end.

Is there a better wait to do so and also make sure the expected output is returned

Comment: In the first SELECT COALESCE statement why not convert the numbers into characters and then sort them that way?

Comment: Converting the numbers to character would sort them as, 1, 10, 2

Answer (score 0):

I think the following will work:

```
order by (case when flat_number ~ '^[0-9]+$' then 0 else 1 end),
         (case when flat_number ~ '^[0-9]+$' then length(flat_number) end),
         flat_number
```

This orders the number first, uses a trick to put them in numeric order, and then orders the rest of the numbers.

Comment: dosent seem to work, I have created a fiddle for it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/10aeb/2

Comment: Also, there's no fixed sequence of chars and numbers, it can be CNCN, NCNCN, NNNCC (N Number, C Char)